# How to object-orientation design a class easy to change component

Tags: java, android, oop

I want to design an android application that sends special SMS. So I want to package my special SMS with some header fields like SMS type, SMS length, and some other information. Then how to I can have a design or data structure that flexible can easy to change the field or order of them later.
Example: I want SMS have field like SMS type (1 byte), SMS version(2 byte), SMS Name Length (1 byte), SMS Name (n byte, n = SMS Name Length)... I need implement two function, one is create sms and other is parse sms field. Here is my example implement.

```java
class Message {
    private byte[] mType;
    private byte[] mVersion;
    private byte[] mNameLength;
    private byte[] mName;

    private byte[] mRawMessage;

    public void create() throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        bo.write(mType, 0, SMS_TYPE_LEN);
        bo.write(mVersion, 0, VERSION_LEN);

        bo.write((byte) mName.length);
        bo.write(mName, 0, mName.length);

        mRawMessage = bo.toByteArray();
    }

    public Message parseFrom(String msg) {
        mRawMessage = Base64.decode(msg, Base64.DEFAULT);
        ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(mRawMessage);

        bi.read(mType, 0, SMS_TYPE_LEN);
        bi.read(mVersion, 0, VERSION_LEN);

        byte[] nameLen= new byte[NAME_LENGTH_LEN];
        bi.read(nameLen, 0, NAME_LENGTH_LEN);
        mName= new byte[Bytes.parseInt(nameLen)];
        bi.read(mName, 0, mName.length);

        return this;
    }
}
```

That have some constant and function I write in other class, but main problem is: if I change the update version of this, may be some field can be added, remove so I need reimplement two function, how can I need modify one only (I think its is SRP in object-orientation)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the help pages, take the SO tour, read about how to ask good questions, as well as this question checklist. Lastly please learn how to create a minimal reproducible example to show us, with emphasis on the minimal part.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @MohammadMasoumi, I edit the question, notify me if have something not clear. Thank you.